# Select with parent in sql using level, right and left ranges

Tags: sql, parent-child, hierarchy

Example table with data:

```
ID_REF    N_LEFT    N_RIGHT    N_LEVEL    DISPLAY_NAME
5854      97        120        1          Students    
5855      98        113        2          Bachelors   
5856      114       115        2          Masters     
440684    105       106        3          2020        
60091     99        102        3          2018        
579034    118       119        2          PhD-DSc     
182954    100       101        4          WithContract
245186    103       104        3          2019        
413700    116       117        2          TKDorm      
694720    107       108        3          2021        
729020    109       110        3          2021Add     
855029    111       112        3          2022
```

`N_LEVEL` saves `parent_child` relations level, `N_LEFT` and `N_RIGHT` columns are ranges of parent_child relations.

How can I select data with hierarchy as shown below:

```
level_1     level_2     level_3     N_LEFT    N_RIGHT    N_LEVEL    DISPLAY_NAME
NULL        NULL        NULL        97        120        1          Students    
Students    NULL        NULL        98        113        2          Bachelors   
Students    NULL        NULL        114       115        2          Masters     
Students    Bachelors   NULL        105       106        3          2020        
Students    Bachelors   NULL        99        102        3          2018        
Students    NULL        NULL        118       119        2          PhD-DSc 
Students    Bachelors   NULL        103       104        3          2019        
Students    NULL        NULL        116       117        2          TKDorm      
Students    Bachelors   NULL        107       108        3          2021        
Students    Bachelors   NULL        109       110        3          2021Add     
Students    Bachelors   NULL        111       112        3          2022
```

My code attempt:

```
SELECT s.ID_REF, s.N_LEFT, s.N_RIGHT, s.N_LEVEL, s.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM SUBDIV_REF S
WHERE ID_REF =5854
and N_left >=97 AND N_right <=120
-- AND n_level=
--create table roles ( id int not null, parentId int, roleName varchar(50) not null );
DECLARE @roles TABLE(id int not null,
    N_LEFT int,
    N_RIGHT int,
    N_LEVEL int,
    DISPLAY_NAME varchar(50))

insert into @roles
    (id, N_LEFT, N_RIGHT,N_LEVEL,DISPLAY_NAME)
values
    (1, 97 , 120 , 1 , 'Students'),
    (2, 98 , 113 , 2 , 'Bachelors'),
    (3, 114 , 115 , 2 , 'Masters'),
    (4, 105 , 106 , 3 , '2020' ),
    (5, 99 , 102 , 3 , '2018'),
    (6, 118 , 119 , 2 , 'PhD-DSc'),
    (7, 103 , 104 , 3 , '2019'),
    (8, 116 , 117 , 2 , 'TKDorm'),
    (9, 107 , 108 , 3 , '2021'),
    (10, 109 , 110 , 3 , '2021Add'),
    (11, 111 , 112 , 3 , '2022')

select * from @roles
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please stop removing copy-pastable text and replacing it with worthless, uncopyable images. See my first comment. If you want to change the data or code in the question, do so as ***TEXT***.

Answer (score 0):

```
--create table roles ( id int not null, parentId int, roleName varchar(50) not null );

DECLARE @roles TABLE(id int not null,N_LEFT int,N_RIGHT int,N_LEVEL int,DISPLAY_NAME varchar(50))

insert into @roles (id, N_LEFT, N_RIGHT,N_LEVEL,DISPLAY_NAME)
values
(1, 97 , 120 , 1 , 'Students'),
(2, 98 , 113 , 2 , 'Bachelors'),
(3, 114 , 115 , 2 , 'Masters'),
(4, 105 , 106 , 3 , '2020' ),
(5, 99 , 102 , 3 , '2018'),
(6, 118 , 119 , 2 , 'PhD-DSc'),
(7, 103 , 104 , 3 , '2019'),
(8, 116 , 117 , 2 , 'TKDorm'),
(9, 107 , 108 , 3 , '2021'),
(10, 109 , 110 , 3 , '2021Add'),
(11, 111 , 112 , 3 , '2022')

 

select 
(select DISPLAY_NAME from @roles where N_Left < R.N_LEFT and N_RIGHT > R.N_RIGHT and N_LEVEL = 1) as Level_1
,(select DISPLAY_NAME from @roles where N_Left < R.N_LEFT and N_RIGHT > R.N_RIGHT and N_LEVEL = 2) as Level_2
,(select DISPLAY_NAME from @roles where N_Left < R.N_LEFT and N_RIGHT > R.N_RIGHT and N_LEVEL = 3) as Level_3

,* from @roles R
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very understandable. But in my condition N_Level is dynamic. It might be more than 10.  How could be this issue solved with dynamic column numbers?